# Windows service calling WebGet method returns 400 error

Tags: c#

I have a service that runs a c# method to sync a database with active directory at a specified interval. This code has worked in a test environment and now putting it on a different server it is returning the following message:

> The server encountered an error processing the request. Please see the
>   service help page for constructing valid requests to the service.

The help page looks like this:

[image]

But the "SyncActiveDirectory" URI is giving me this error:

[image]

This is a new server. Maybe i am missing something that needs to be installed or a setting in IIS? Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT:
Here is the method that called the webget:

```
private void SyncActiveDirectoryServiceCall()
        {
            WriteIntoLogFile("Start _schedulerService.SyncActiveDirectoryServiceCall()");

            try
            {
                var reader = new AppSettingsReader();
                var serviceurl = reader.GetValue("ServiceUrl", typeof(string));
                var client = new RestSharp.RestClient(serviceurl.ToString());
                var request = new RestSharp.RestRequest("SyncActiveDirectory", RestSharp.Method.GET);
                var response = client.Execute(request);
                WriteIntoLogFile(response.Content);
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                using (WebResponse response = ex.Response)
                {
                    HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)response;

                    WriteIntoLogFile("Error code: " + httpResponse.StatusCode);

                    using (Stream data = response.GetResponseStream())
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(data))
                    {
                        string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        WriteIntoLogFile("STREAMED: " + text);
                    }
                }
                WriteIntoLogFile("TRY-CATCH: " + ex.ToString());
            }
            WriteIntoLogFile("End _schedulerService.SyncActiveDirectoryServiceCall()");

        }
```

And here is the method being called:

```
namespace SyncActiveDirectory
{
    public class SyncLocalWithLDAP : ISyncLocalWithLDAP
    {
        private List<GenericUser> users { get; set; }
        private List<GenericUser> roles { get; set; }
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "SyncActiveDirectory")]
        public void SyncActiveDirectory()
        {
            string constr = GetConnectionStringValue("ProteusMMXCustomerDB");
            string usr = GetAppsettingValue("ldap_login_username");
            string pss = GetAppsettingValue("ldap_login_password");
            string filePath = string.Empty;
            ActiveDirectoryWrapper wrapper = new ActiveDirectoryWrapper();
            if (!Directory.Exists(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogFolderPath"] + "ServiceLog"))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogFolderPath"] + "ServiceLog");
            }
            if (!File.Exists(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogFolderPath"] + "ServiceLog" + "/" + "SyncLog.txt"))
            {
                File.Create(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogFolderPath"] + "ServiceLog" + "/" + "SyncLog.txt").Dispose();
            }

            filePath = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogFolderPath"] + "ServiceLog" + @"\" + "SyncLog.txt";

            using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(filePath))
            {
                Log("Constr - " + constr + " , u - " + usr + " p - " + pss, w);
                try
                {
                    Log("Start sync outer", w);
                    SyncLocalWithLDAP_Users_Roles(constr, usr, pss, w);
                    Log("End sync outer", w);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Log("Error: " + ex.Message, w);
                }
            }
        }
```

EDIT:
Pic of htm file added to that directory. 
[image]

EDIT:
If this helps here is Chrome Developer Tools headers:
[image]

Comment: Can you share the code the SyncActiveDirectory runs? What does it request of the AD server?

Comment: Edited post with more code.

Comment: Add a file to the directory where the service is installed and IIS has it as a web site, such as helloworld.htm. Can you browse to that file?

Comment: I tried your suggestion and added a .htm file to the website and I was able to browse that file. Added picture of that to post.

Comment: any ideas @petryuno1 ?

Comment: or @OmegaMan, have you got any ideas? I've been trying to troubleshoot this issue for a few days with no progress. Anything would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Any more info about the configuration of this AD environment compared to your test environment? Are you using the same web.config in IIS? There must be a setting disparity somewhere.

Comment: The AD environment is the same on both servers. I tried using the same web.config in both environments only changing the connection string value.

Comment: Publish debug code to the remote site and remote debug into it. It seems that IIS is serving up pages fine (as shown by the test page) but something is being garbled getting to the rest calls?